# PHP Email Confirmation Function MySQL Database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

There are many questions about email confirmation, databases, and permissions on Stackoverflow, but nothing I could find that would help me with this.

This specific question is directed to an email confirmation function built with PHP. The tutorial I am using can be found here: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/24.html.  Everything is working, however when the user clicks the email confirmation link (which would move their information from the `temp_table` to the `confirmed_table`), I receive this error:

> Error updating database: No database selected

From what I have gathered from different sites/research/Stackoverflow questions is that this is due to the permissions of the database(s) I am working with (please correct me if it is another problem). I have read that I need to change all the users to be able to `READ`, but am unsure whether I should do this to both the databases as a whole (I couldn't find whether you can set the privileges for all the users in a database to automatically have the `READ` privileged), or the PHP when I add them to the `temp_table`.  The tutorial I showed above doesn't say anything about it, so I am confused.

Registration form code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['aI']) || isset($_SESSION['pss'])) {
        header("Location: pa.php");
    }

    include 'db.php';

    if(isset($_POST['rSub'])) {
        // connects to database using PHP Data Objects, throws exception if error in connection
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$svrHost;db=$svrDb", $sUme, $sp);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $error = '';

        if($_POST['fN'] == '' || $_POST['lN'] == '' || $_POST['aI'] == '' || $_POST['eml'] == '' || $_POST['pss'] == ''
            || $_POST['pss2'] == '') {
            $error = "<li style=\"color:#C70000; font-weight:bold;\"><center>- All fields are required. Try again.</font><center></li>";
        }
        if($error == '') {
            $fN = ucfirst($_POST['fN']);
            $lN = ucfirst($_POST['lN']);
            $aI = $_POST['aI'];
            $eml = $_POST['eml'];
            $pss = $_POST['pss'];
            $pss2 = $_POST['pss2'];
            $admin = 0;


        if($error != '') {
            $error = "<ul>".$error."</ul>";
            $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
        }
        else {
            $hF = "$2y$10$"; // 2y = blowfish and 10 = num of hashes
            $sa = "testsaltforwebsite1219"; //"random" 22-character sa
            $fAS = $hF.$sa;
            $sha = crypt($pss, $fAS);
            // Random confirmation code
            $c_cd=md5(uniqid(rand()));

            $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO t_awhole (c_cd, fN, lN, aI, eml, pss) 
                    VALUES (:c_cd, :fN, :lN, :aI, :eml, :pss)");

            $insert->bindParam(':c_cd', $c_cd);
            $insert->bindParam(':fN', $fN);
            $insert->bindParam(':lN', $lN);
            $insert->bindParam(':aI', $aI);
            $insert->bindParam(':eml', $eml);           
            $insert->bindParam(':pss', $sha);
            $result=$insert->execute();

            // ---------------- Confirmation email ---------------- \\
            // table name 
            $t_apart=t_awhole;

            if($result){

            // send e-mail to ...
            $to=$eml;

            // Your subject
            $subject="Registration Confirmation";

            // From
            $header="from: no-reply@example.com"; //Need the address to send the eml to.

            // Your message
            $message="Copy and paste this link in your browser to activate your account: \r\n";
            $message.="\n";
            $message.="(serverAddress)/confirmation.php?passkey=$c_cd \r\n";
            $message.="\n";
            $message.="Thank you";

            // send eml
            $sml = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
            }

            // if not found
            else {
            echo "Your email Is Not Registered.  Please Register.";
            }

            // if your email succesfully sent
            if($sml){
            echo '<script> window.location.href="emlC.php"</script>';
            }

            else {
            echo "Cannot Send Confirmation Link To Your email Address.";
            }
            // ---------------- Confirmation email ---------------- \\
            $_SESSION['aI'] = $aI;
            $_SESSION['pss'] = $pss;
            $_SESSION['admin'] = 0;

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT dN, dU, ex FROM doc WHERE aI != '0'");
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            foreach ($result as $row)
            {

                $ex = $row['ex'];
                $dU = $row['dU'];
                $dN = $row['dN'];


                $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO doc (dN, dU, aI, ex)
                        VALUES (:dN, :dU, :aI, :ex)");


                $insert->bindParam(':aI', $aI);
                $insert->bindParam(':ex', $ex);
                $insert->bindParam(':dU', $dU);
                $insert->bindParam(':dN', $dN);

                $insert->execute();

            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Confirmation page code:

```
<?php

include('db.php');

// passkey that got from link
$pk=$_GET['pk'];
$t_awhole_conf="t_awhole";

// Retrieve data from table where row that match this passkey
$sql_conf1="SELECT * FROM $t_awhole_conf WHERE confirm_code ='$pk'";
$result_conf=mysql_query($sql_conf1) or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());


// If successfully queried
if($result_conf){
    // Count how many row has this passkey
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result_conf);

        // if found this passkey in our database, retrieve data from table "t_awhole"
        if($count==1){

            $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result_conf);
            $fN = $rows['fN']; // capitalizes the first letter (6-26-14)
            $lN = $rows['lN']; // capitalizes the first letter (6-26-14)
            $aI = $rows['aI'];
            $eml = $rows['eml'];
            $pss = $rows['pss'];
            $pss2 = $rows['pss2'];

            $a_whole_conf="a_whole";

            // Insert data that retrieves from "t_awhole" into table "a_whole"
            $sql_conf2="INSERT INTO $a_whole_conf(fN, lN, aI, eml, pss, admin) 
                                VALUES ($fN, $lN, $aI, $eml, $pss, $admin)";
            $result_conf2=mysql_query($sql_conf2);
        }

        // if not found passkey, display message "Wrong Confirmation code"
        else {
            echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
        }

        // if successfully moved data from table"t_awhole" to table "a_whole" displays message "Your account has been activated" and don't forget to delete confirmation code from table "t_awhole"
        if($result_conf2){

            echo "Your account has been activated";

            // Delete information of this user from table "t_awholeb" that has this passkey
            $sql_conf3="DELETE FROM $t_awhole_conf WHERE confirm_code = '$pk'";
            $result_conf3=mysql_query($sql_conf3);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How are you initialising your database connection? Please show the code

Comment: Sidenote: That tutorial is old, outdated and is open to SQL injection (big time). I recommend you find something else using `mysqli_` with prepared statements or convert it to `mysqli_` while making sure to **not** store passwords as plain text while using a proper/safe hashing algo. If you using that tutorial as is, it's just a matter of time before you get hacked; you've been advised.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Right.  Was getting the basic function down then going to work on security after it was working.

Comment: @Alex I updated the question with code.  Didn't think it was necessary as I am asking a more general question.

Comment: It is necessary because that is the point at which you would select which database you are using. If you are moving from one database to another, you will want to select that other database before using it. Or refer to its full name in your insert query: `database.table`

Comment: Hmm.  I'm confused as to what you're saying.

The way I have it set up is it will go to the temp_table (which is on the production server and not even shown in the code), and then after that confirmation link is accessed, it will move that info to the confirmed_table.

Comment: If you could further explain, that would be great.  I don't know where to implement the the database.table query.  Still learning php/mysqli, so some more direction would be great.

Comment: The obvious cause here is that you are not connecting to the database correctly. Does this confirmation code live in a separate file to the code that you say is working?

Comment: OK.  The registration form code is where the confirmation code is created (as `$c_cd=md5(uniqid(rand()));`).  The confirmation page code I added is where the data from the temporary database moves to the permanent database.  Does that provide what you're looking for?

Comment: If you look at the line with `or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());` you'll see where the problem is.  For some reason it isn't running the `mysql_query()` function properly.  That's where the problem lies and is what lead me to believe it has to do with the permissions of the table or the user itself - which is what my original question was.  If I am mislead, please enlighten me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Registration form code, you have two lines that create the connection to the database (new PDO ...). You can further use $conn to execute statements.

In your Confirmation code, you don't create any connection before calling mysql_query (why the switch from PDO to mysql functions ?).

See the mysql_query documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: OK.  What would you suggest doing? I did it this way as I was following the guide I posted in the question.

Comment: My first reaction would be to completly change one file or the other, to choose if you want to go with PDO (Registration file) or mysql (Confirmation file). I'd go with PDO, cause the other deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Comment: Instead, if you only want this to work quickly, I think that you only miss a "connect" line in your Confirmation file to succeed. Something like mysql_connect(host, user, pass), then mysql_select_db(db). See mysql functions here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php.